# Need to tell when UIImageviews overlap

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm currently programming an app that deals with line graphs. I have three "dots" that allow the user to move the whole line or rotate it, one for the former and two for the latter. The problem that I'm having, though, is that sometimes the dots end up overlapping each other. If I try to touch one of the dots that rotate the graph when that happens, it just moves the whole graph itself, as if I'm touching the moving dot. What I want to know is if there is a simple way to calculate whether a uiimageview is overlapping another? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming they have the same superview:

```
NSIntersectsRect(imageView1.frame, imageView2.frame)
```

If they have different superviews, you may need to use [`-convertRect:toView:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/convertRect%3atoView%3a) and friends.